# how to apply filters on mysql result set

Tags: mysql, filter, where-clause, resultset

i want to apply different filters on my result set so that i can retrive excat result of the filters, and is not necessary that each time this filters will have some value it may contain null value as well , so ho to use such filters 
below is my table

```
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `categoryid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `labelid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `datetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `ispublic` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `value` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=15 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERTed VALUES
INSERT INTO `my_schema`.`data`
(
`title`,
`url`,
`categoryid`,
`labelid`,
`datetime`,
`ispublic`,
`value`)
VALUES
('newclip','http://newclip/',1,1,'2014-11-21 10:40:49',1,3.5),
('newclip url','http://newclip/fisrt/',1,3,'2014-12-21 10:40:49',0,3),
('newclip123','http://newclip123/',2,1,'2014-11-20 10:40:50',1,3.5),
('clip','http://clip/',4,2,'2014-10-21 1:40:49',0,3.5),
('new','http://new/',5,3,'2014-11-25 10:50:49',0,2),
('music','http://newclip/mucis',1,2,'2014-12-21 10:40:49',1,3.5),
('newclip','http://newclip/',4,6,'2014-11-28 10:40:49',0,5),
('newclip','http://newclip/',6,7,'2014-11-21 10:40:49',1,3.5),
('newclip url','http://newclip/fisrt/',1,2,'2014-12-21 10:40:49',0,3),
('newclip123','http://newclip123/',2,1,'2014-11-20 10:40:50',1,3.5),
('clip','http://clip/',1,2,'2014-10-21 1:40:49',0,3.5),
('new','http://new/',1,2,'2014-11-25 10:50:49',0,2),
('music','http://newclip/movie',1,2,'2014-12-21 10:40:49',1,3.5),
('newclip','http://newclip/',1,2,'2014-11-28 10:40:49',0,5)
```

query to search for a particular record is applied to only title & url, i want to retrive all record which have 'newclip' in title or in url.

SELECT * FROM my_schema.data WHERE title LIKE '%newclip%' OR url LIKE '%newclip%';

using above query i get the all records which have newclip in url or title

now i want to apply filters on this result set, filters could b using categoryid,labelid,datetime,ispublic,values etc will b applyed on it.

how to filter such result set,
any help will be appreciated , thank you

Answer (score 1):

Include those Filter(s) in a outer query, which will be applied to the result set obtained by the inner query. Something like

```
select * from
(
SELECT * FROM my_schema.data 
WHERE title LIKE '%newclip%' 
OR url LIKE '%newclip%'
) tab 
where categoryid = 3
or labelid = 4;
```

Comment: but if user doesnt provide categoryid , it could be null if it doesnt select category id, in such condition what to do

Comment: wowww that cool, i havent thought about it, great i will try this, what will be the value for input in isnull function

Comment: Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: That should be whatever end user passes and input value.

Comment: @pitu, Ahh!! my bad; it's for MySQL. In that case use `COALESCE` function like `where categoryid = COALESCE(input,3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from 
    (SELECT * FROM my_schema.data WHERE title 
     LIKE '%newclip%' OR url LIKE '%newclip%') `temp_tbl` 
WHERE condition here...
```